# Detect Twitter and Facebook Notifications in my App

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, sdk, notifications

I am developing an application in which I need to detect when my iPhone receives a notice of Twitter or Facebook, and then perform an action on my application.

example: I'm hardware developer and would like to make an application when a notification arrives me, flashing a LED (independent of the iPhone).
What need would be to know if it is possible to detect from my application notifications from other applications, and what is the way to do it, because I have knowledge in ios development.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you able to flash the LED using iPhone application as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't detect notification from other apps, since apps are sandboxed.

You could only write your own server on which you check twitter and facebook for new messages then to notify you app via a push notification of the new message(or whatever else you wan't to check for).

Comment: We are also looking for the same type of feature in our iOS and Android applications. Here we are using Facebook Graph API and we have to use "manage_notification" permission to access the things like new like, comment, new wall post on user's wall. Will "manage_notification" permission allow us to do the needful? Please let us know if you have any idea about this one.

Comment: @AppAspect please don't ask a question in a comment, no one will notice it. Just post your now question!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Twitter Streams API to get notifications about Twitter activities.

Use this post:
[Twitter iOS Streaming API: no data being received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621211/twitter-ios-streaming-api-no-data-being-received?lq=1)